# extract the name without the domain into a new xpath field

Tags: xml, xpath, sharepoint

I am trying to get the following data:

```
http://siteurl/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Supervisor')/Items?$select=Supervisor/Title,Supervisor/Name,substring-after(Supervisor/Name,"\\")&$expand=Supervisor
```

However I am getting the following error:

> The expression
>   "Supervisor/Title,Supervisor/Name,substring-after(Supervisor/Name,"\")"
>   is not valid.

My objective is to extract the name without the domain into a new xpath field.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The substring-after method can't supported in REST API.

If you only want to get the username with the domain, we just use Supervisor/Title to achieve it.

```
http://siteurl/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Supervisor')/Items?$select=Supervisor/Title&$expand=Supervisor
```